# I am getting error with native query when I shift from mysql to mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using mysql with Spring boot application, but now need to use mongodb. I'm getting error with native query in mysql. native query code for nearby distance is here:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT\n"
        + "  branchid\n"
        + " , ("
        + "    3959 * acos (\n"
        + "      cos ( radians(:latParam) )\n"
        + "      * cos( radians( lat ) )\n"
        + "      * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(:lonParam ) )\n"
        + "      + sin ( radians(:latParam ) )\n"
        + "      * sin( radians( lat ) )\n"
        + "    )\n"
        + "  ) AS distance\n"
        + "FROM ambservice_branch\n"
        + "HAVING distance < :radiusParam \n"
        + "ORDER BY distance\n"
        + "LIMIT 0 , 20;", nativeQuery = true)
```

Please help me out to convert this query to mongodb query.
this is actual mysql query.

> SELECT branchid, (3959 
>       * acos (cos ( radians(:latParam) )
>       * cos( radians( lat ) )
>       * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(:lonParam ) )
>       + sin ( radians(:latParam ) )
>       * sin( radians( lat ) ))) AS distance
>       FROM ambservice_branch
>       HAVING distance < :radiusParam 
>       ORDER BY distance
>       LIMIT 0 , 20;